# jQuery scrollTop() autoscroll by increment works on some sites, but not others. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop, scrollto, autoscroll

I've found a (working) script which will autoscroll a webpage by a set number of pixels:

```
var y = $(window).scrollTop(); $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: '+=291px'}, 300);
```

This script works on some sites, but not others. e.g.,

The script works on: Twitter.com, BBC.co.uk, Reddit.com

The script **doesn't** work on: Facebook.com, Instagram.com, Pinterest.com... and shows one of the following error messages:

> VM104:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of
>   undefined at :1:18

(Pinterest & Instagram)

or

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollTop is not a function at
>   :1:19

(Facebook)

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening, and how we can fix it? I'd love to know.

Cheers, StackOverflow!

Comment: by 'a script', you mean, when you type it in the brower console?

Comment: Those sites doesn't use jQuery I believed

Comment: use pure JS and pure animation with JS as well, if you want to make it work on all sites, you can check `jQuery` if undefined or not

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS? `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop = 0`

Or do you need to animate?

EDIT......

With animation

```
function scrollToTop(){  

  var scrollHeight = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollHeight;
```

```js
function scrollToTop(){  
 var scrollAtATime = 10;
 var scrollHeight = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollHeight;
 var t = window.setInterval(function(){

   document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop = scrollHeight;

   scrollHeight-=scrollAtATime;
   
   //Add Easing
   scrollAtATime = scrollHeight / 100;

   if(Math.ceil(scrollHeight) <= 1) window.clearInterval(t);
   
  },1);
   
}
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:2000px;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
<button onclick="javascript:scrollToTop()">Click to scroll</button>
```

Comment: OP wants a workaround, you should've put this in the comment section

Comment: This is a workaround.... some sites dont use jquery so why not plain js?

Comment: will that make the animation work? base from his code? put the animation code as well

Comment: I dont know why stackoverflow is adding something to that example but it works in codepen --EDIT-- Dont use console log in example lol

Comment: You should never use setInterval IMO, especially with such a low interval (`1ms`), and super especially when the callback is causing the page to repaint. Use requestAnimationFrame, and every time the function executes check to see if you're done, if not call rAF again. [Here's why](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)